# Install from local git repository located in a file system directory

Tags: r, git, devtools

Is it possible to use `devtools::install_git()` to install a package from a **local** git repository located in some file system directory on MS Windows?

The examples only demonstrate how to install from a web URL (e.g. `install_git("git://github.com/hadley/stringr.git")`).

From within a package loaded via RStudio and devtools (CTRL + SHFT + L) and under git version control (i.e., subdirectory `.git` exists) , I tried the following:

```
devtools::install_git(paste0("git://", getwd(), ".git"))
```

The function came back with this error:

```
Downloading git repo git://C:/Users/Thyson/Documents/path/to/package/packagename.git
Error in git2r::clone(x$url, bundle, progress = FALSE) : 
  Error in 'git2r_clone': Malformed URL 'git://C:/Users/Thyson/Documents/path/to/package/packagename.git'
```

So I'm guessing I just got the file system URL wrong?

Comment: The issue is probably your use of the git:// prefix, which implies that the repo is remote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a same problem in MS Windows before and figured it out myself. For example, if you have a local repository called "C:\path\to\pkga.git".

> devtools::install_git("C://path/to/pkga.git")

The key is to use double slash in the path "C://path/to/pkga.git".

Hope that works for other using MS Windows.

Comment: thanks! hadn't tried double forward slashes...tried plenty of other combinations though, including `file://`

Answer (score 8):

Why using `devtools::install_git`? You can use `devtools::install` instead.

```
library("devtools")
install()
```